# Getting error while importing onnxruntime ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_providers' (Windows 10)

Tags: importerror, onnx, onnxruntime

I have installed onnxruntime-gpu library in my environment

```
pip install onnxruntime-gpu==1.2.0

nvcc --version output
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105

>>> import onnxruntime
C:\Users\abgangwa\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\onnx_gpu\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\_pybind_state.py:13: UserWarning: Cannot load onnxruntime.capi. Error: 'DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.'
  warnings.warn("Cannot load onnxruntime.capi. Error: '{0}'".format(str(e)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\abgangwa\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\onnx_gpu\lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from onnxruntime.capi._pybind_state import get_all_providers, get_available_providers, get_device, RunOptions, SessionOptions, set_default_logger_severity, NodeArg, ModelMetadata, GraphOptimizationLevel, ExecutionMode
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_providers'
```

Please help me to resolve this error

Tried existing solutions. none of them worked

Answer (score 2):

Just install the Suitable version :

`pip install onnxruntime` #for CPU-only

`pip install onnxruntime-gpu` #For GPU

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you explain how that solves the issue that is described in the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the CUDA dlls aren't in the path so aren't found when the onnxruntime library is being loaded by python.

This reply has a link to an article regarding fixing this.

https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/4196#issuecomment-808787338